# "SMOTE makes the assumption that the instance between a positive class instance and its nearest neighbors is also positive"

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, resampling, smote

I am trying to get my head around this assertion  by [Liu, Y. et al (2011 pp. 7)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030645731000097X) about SMOTE oversampling technique that:

> because SMOTE makes the assumption that the instance between a positive class instance and its nearest neigh-
> bors is also positive. However it may not always be true in practice. As a positive instance is very close to the boundary, its
> nearest neighbor is likely to be negative, and this possibility may increase as K and the imbalance ratio become larger.

Maybe I am wrong but what I understand is that SMOTE selects the ***K neighbours*** from the minority (positive) class only, and generates synthetic sample along the line joining the minority example and those K-samples of the same class.

By having these authors claim that it may not always be true, I am confused. Does that mean a majority (negative) example maybe selected among *K samples*? Can anyone digest to mean what this actually means? I cannot understand what exactly the authors mean by this paragraph concluding statement.

**Reference**

Liu, Y., Yu, X., Huang, J.X. and An, A., 2011. Combining integrated sampling with SVM ensembles for learning from imbalanced datasets. Information Processing & Management, 47(4), pp.617-631.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original paper makes it clear that the nearest neighbours are from the minority class, so it appears that Liu et al. are mistaken.

[image]

Having said which, I am not sure the paper is entirely consistent with most implementations (or indeed itself)

[image]

I think for the synthetic point to be on a line joining the selected minority point with it's nearest neighbour, $gap$ would have to be assigned outside the loop over attributes, not inside it.

BTW if you are using a modern classifier, such as an SVM, that can implement cost-sensitive learning and has a good means of avoiding overfitting, then I would advise against using SMOTE.  Techniques such as regularisation have a lot of solid theory behind them, the method used by SMOTE has none.  I would also advise using a probabilistic classifier for problems with unequal misclassification costs etc. as you can account for the misclassification costs after the model has been fitted to the data.

Comment: Ah, moment of relief..lol. +1 for your piece of advice.